# How to call a value from cell of array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have this cell array in my Matlab code

```
energie{n} = [Ea, Ed];
```

In which Ea contain 1 value and Ed contain 3 values i don't know how to call the second value of Ed .
For example if  i have this

```
Ea =
 50.9982

 Ed =
 1.1777   19.0690   20.2442    8.5108
```

and i want to call '19.0690' how can i do it ?

I tried this

```
ans=energie{1:n:3}
```

but it give me

50.9982  1.1777   19.0690   20.2442    8.5108

Also i tried

```
energie{n}{2}(3)
```

But i got this error message

"Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object."

Answer (score 0):

`energie{n}` is a 5 element matrix.  You are wanting the 3rd element of it, so `energie{n}(3)` will give you the element.

If you had done `energie{n} = {Ea Ed}` then `energie{n}` is a cell array containing 2 elements, where the first element is a scalar and the second element is a 4 element vector.  In this case `energie{n}{2}(2)` would work.

Comment: Ok it works now thanks